# SQLite concurrent connections issue

Tags: vb.net, system.data.sqlite, sqlite

I am working on a VB.NET application.
As per the nature of the application, One module has to monitor database (SQLite DB) each second. This Monitoring is done by simple select statement which run to check data against some condition.
Other Modules performs a select,Insert and Update statements on same SQLite DB.
on SQLite concurrent select statements are working fine, but I'm having hard time here to find out, why it is not allowing Inset and Update.
I understand it's a file based lock, but is there anyway to get it done?
each module, in fact statement opens and close the connection to DB.
I've restricted user to run single statement at a time by GUI design.

any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your database file is not on a network, you could allow a certain amount of read/write concurrency by enabling [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

But perhaps you should use only a single connection and do your own synchronization for all DB accesses.

Comment: Thank you for replying.Now  I am doing it all in a single thread (Form). even if that thread get closed, second thread (Same form) will be opened. And YES it is not a Network Based File. Not sure how to use WAL mode. Can you help me with a piece of code spinet in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some locking mechanism to make sure the database works in a multithreading situation. Since your application is a read intensive one according to what you said, you can consider using a ReaderWriterLock or ReaderWriterLockSlim. (refer to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) for more details)

If you have only one database, then creating just one instance of the lock is OK; if you have more than one database, each of them can be assigned a lock. Every time you do some read or write, enter the lock (by EnterReadLock() for ReaderWriterLockSlim, or by AcquireReaderLock() for ReaderWriterLock) before you do something, and after you're done exit the lock. Note that you can place the exit of the lock in a finally clause lest you forget to release it.

The strategy above is being used in our production applications. It's not so good as to use a single thread in your case because you have to take performance into account.